# transfer each letter of an string array into integers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the task to transfer each letter of a given sequence into an integer vector in matlab. For instance, given the input sequence, 'seq = TGCA'. Since here we totally have 4 distinct letters, I plan to encode 'A' as '0001', encode 'T' as '0010', encode 'G' as '0100' and encode 'C' as '1000'. And then the whole sequence can be encoded as the contenationn of all the encoded (0,1) vectors. So, in this case, the whole sequence would be '0010010010000001'. Any comments would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose? What if we have more unique characters? As well `0001` looks more binary than an integer itself.

Comment: Seing TGCA, I guess it's DNA related, isn't it?

Comment: @Matt, if we have more unique characters, then we would increase the size of the vectors.

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior, it can be more generalized. Does not matter too much whether it is DNA related or not.

Comment: In your question you are asking for 'comments'. Do you need an algorithm converting it how you mentioned or something else?

Comment: Why not encode the letters as `0, 1, 2, 3` (or `00, 01, 10, 11`)? Then you can get 4 letters in one byte. :)

Comment: @Matt, I know how to it in standard way, like transform each letter one by one. But I do not know how to do it in a vectorization fashion.

Comment: That's what I thought. Please edit your question to state that you want a vectorized solution for it, so others know this directly. @beaker: seems he likes one-hot encoding...

Comment: @beaker, you can do it that way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this solution is to define a key, which returns the expected output when compared to the string:

```
>> key='CGTA'

key =

CGTA

>> key=='A'

ans =

     0     0     0     1

>> key=='T'

ans =

     0     0     1     0
```

This basically solves it, now use bsxfun to vectorize:

```
E=reshape(bsxfun(@eq,key(:),seq(:).'),1,[])
```

This outputs a logical vector, if char is inteded use:

```
F=char(reshape(bsxfun(@eq,key(:),seq(:).'),1,[])+'0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Octave doesn't support `containers.Map`, so I'm gonna waste 80 rows out of an 84x4 matrix...

```
codes(['A','T','G','C'],:)=['0001';'0010';'0100';'1000'];
seq = 'ATACAGCTAGGATCA';

encodedSeq=codes(seq,:);

encodedSeq =

0001
0010
0001
1000
0001
0100
1000
0010
0001
0100
0100
0001
0010
1000
0001
```

or

```
reshape(encodedSeq,1,[])
ans = 000100100000010000001000110000010000010000100101010001001001
```